# Seaborn barplot unsupported data type

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm a newbie in pandas and seaborn.
I have a simple CSV file like this:

```
quarter;industry1;industry2;industry3;job_vacancy
1990-Q1;manufacturing;food, beverages and tobacco;food, beverages and tobacco;500
1990-Q1;manufacturing;textile and wearing apparel;textile and wearing apparel;5100
1990-Q1;manufacturing;paper products and publishing;paper products and publishing;1100
1990-Q1;manufacturing;petroleum and chemical products;petroleum and chemical products;600
1990-Q1;manufacturing;rubber and plastic products;rubber and plastic products;100
```

In Jupyter notebook, I'm trying to plot a bar graph.

[image]

So far it's fine.
But the real data is not all numeric. So for example, I change the value of the last row to be "-".

```
quarter;industry1;industry2;industry3;job_vacancy
1990-Q1;manufacturing;food, beverages and tobacco;food, beverages and tobacco;500
1990-Q1;manufacturing;textile and wearing apparel;textile and wearing apparel;5100
1990-Q1;manufacturing;paper products and publishing;paper products and publishing;1100
1990-Q1;manufacturing;petroleum and chemical products;petroleum and chemical products;600
1990-Q1;manufacturing;rubber and plastic products;rubber and plastic products;-
```

When I tried to run the same code, I'll receive an error:
[image]

yadayadayada, the point is:
[image]

May I know what's actually going on? I know there are non-numeric value in the whole dataframe, but I thought I'm only getting the top 3 of the whole data, and they all have numeric value for "job_vacancy" column?

How should I do it to make the bar graph?

### **Edit:**

I somehow make it work. The way I do it is to make a deep copy of the dataframe, and thanks to @asongtoruin, set everything to numeric.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";")
data = df.loc[:2].copy(1)
data.head()
data['job_vacancy'] = pd.to_numeric(arg=data['job_vacancy'],errors='coerce').fillna(0)
snsplot = sns.barplot(x="industry3", y="job_vacancy", data=data, orient="v")
```

Now I'm just wondering if this is the correct or proper way to do it.

Comment: The non-numeric value is changing the type of the entire column. Try `data['job_vacancy'] = data['job_vacancy'].to_numeric(errors='coerce').fillna(0)`

Comment: Thanks, but that will give error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'". 
I used `pd.to_numeric(arg=data['job_vacancy'],errors='coerce').fillna(0)` instead.

Comment: Simply clean the column of those non-numeric values and then convert column to numeric type. By the way, consider reshaping your dataframe to long format which is much easier to work with than wide. Any dataset with numbered suffixes is a candidate for reshaping (i.e., industry1, industry2, industry3). If this was a database table, the DBA should be crying himself/herself to sleep!

Comment: *Now I'm just wondering if this is the correct or proper way to do it.*...check the source of your file and find why it is not valid numbers.